reboot following shutdown
I have a specific problem with my hp probook g9 laptop.
If the power supply (via usb-c) and HDMI cable are connected, then after shutting down the Linux system, it restarts. This does not happen in the case of Windows (which always shuts down successfuly).
And in the case of linux, this does not happen when I disconnect one of the cables - HDMI or power supply.
The laptop is still under warranty for half a year, but HP service says that if it works on windows, it is not a hardware problem and they will not do anything about it.
I have no idea how to deal with this. Disconnecting the cable before every shutdown of the computer is inconvenient and is frustrating me more and more. I tried to look through the logs, but nothing useful results from them for me.
First of all, which logs should I begin with? I've tried this one:
sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e

But nothing useful turned out for me.
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook sudo[4481]:   wojtek : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/wojtek ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl poweroff --force
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook sudo[4481]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by wojtek(uid=1000)
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1]: Shutting down.
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook sudo[4481]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices.
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes...
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd-journald[357]: Received SIGTERM from PID 1 (systemd-shutdow).
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook kernel: wlp3s0: deauthenticating from d8:07:b6:7b:bc:d7 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook wireplumber[1975]: stopped by signal: Terminated
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook snapd[833]: main.go:168: Exiting on terminated signal.
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd-logind[844]: Failed to remove file descriptor "session-2-device-13-68" from the store, ignoring: Connection refused
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd-logind[844]: Failed to remove file descriptor "session-2-device-13-66" from the store, ignoring: Connection refused
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook avahi-daemon[811]: Got SIGTERM, quitting.
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd-logind[844]: Failed to remove file descriptor "session-2-device-13-65" from the store, ignoring: Connection refused
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook avahi-daemon[811]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp3s0.IPv6 with address fe80::7587:6929:ad04:b46c.
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd-logind[844]: Failed to remove file descriptor "session-2-device-13-71" from the store, ignoring: Connection refused
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook thermald[845]: Terminating ...
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd-logind[844]: Failed to remove file descriptor "session-2-device-13-72" from the store, ignoring: Connection refused
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook bluetoothd[812]: Terminating
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd-logind[844]: Failed to remove file descriptor "session-2-device-13-79" from the store, ignoring: Connection refused
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook bluetoothd[812]: Disconnected from D-Bus. Exiting.
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd-logind[844]: Failed to remove file descriptor "session-2-device-13-73" from the store, ignoring: Connection refused
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook bluetoothd[812]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/ldac
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd-logind[844]: Failed to remove file descriptor "session-2-device-13-67" from the store, ignoring: Connection refused
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook bluetoothd[812]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/aptx_hd
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd-logind[844]: Failed to remove file descriptor "session-2-device-13-70" from the store, ignoring: Connection refused
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook bluetoothd[812]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx_hd
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd-logind[844]: Failed to remove file descriptor "session-2-device-226-1" from the store, ignoring: Connection refused
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook bluetoothd[812]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/aptx
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd-logind[844]: Failed to remove file descriptor "session-2-device-13-64" from the store, ignoring: Connection refused
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook bluetoothd[812]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd-logind[844]: Failed to remove file descriptor "session-2-device-13-80" from the store, ignoring: Connection refused
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook bluetoothd[812]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Activating special unit exit.target...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook bluetoothd[812]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopped vte-spawn-cd641fe3-7719-4bb6-8bb2-f952aa7df81e.scope - VTE child process 4472 launched by gnome-terminal-server process 4464.
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook bluetoothd[812]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping app-gnome-at\x2dspi\x2ddbus\x2dbus-2236.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook bluetoothd[812]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping app-gnome-google\x2dchrome-3002.scope - Application launched by gnome-shell...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook bluetoothd[812]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx_ll_1
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping app-gnome-org.gnome.Evolution\x2dalarm\x2dnotify-2441.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook bluetoothd[812]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx_ll_0
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook NetworkManager[870]: <info>  [1732292000.2941] caught SIGTERM, shutting down normally.
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook bluetoothd[812]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx_ll_duplex_1
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping app-gnome-org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.DiskUtilityNotify-2493.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook bluetoothd[812]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx_ll_duplex_0
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping app-gnome-update\x2dnotifier-3554.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook power-profiles-daemon[823]: GLib-GIO       Error releasing name org.freedesktop.UPower.PowerProfiles: The connection is closed
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook bluetoothd[812]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/faststream
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopped target bluetooth.target - Bluetooth.
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook bluetoothd[812]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/faststream_duplex
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopped target default.target - Main User Target.
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook bluetoothd[812]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/opus_05
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopped target gnome-session-wayland@ubuntu.target - GNOME Wayland Session (session: ubuntu).
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook bluetoothd[812]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/opus_05
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping dconf.service - User preferences database...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook bluetoothd[812]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/opus_05_duplex
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping evolution-addressbook-factory.service - Evolution address book service...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook bluetoothd[812]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/opus_05_duplex
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping evolution-calendar-factory.service - Evolution calendar service...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook avahi-daemon[811]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp3s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.0.102.
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping evolution-source-registry.service - Evolution source registry...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook avahi-daemon[811]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface lo.IPv6 with address ::1.
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping filter-chain.service - PipeWire filter chain daemon...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook avahi-daemon[811]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface lo.IPv4 with address 127.0.0.1.
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping gnome-terminal-server.service - GNOME Terminal Server...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook ModemManager[926]: <msg> caught signal, shutting down...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping gvfs-afc-volume-monitor.service - Virtual filesystem service - Apple File Conduit monitor...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook rsyslogd[941]: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.2312.0" x-pid="941" x-info="https://www.rsyslog.com"] exiting on signal 15.
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping gvfs-daemon.service - Virtual filesystem service...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook avahi-daemon[811]: avahi-daemon 0.8 exiting.
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping gvfs-goa-volume-monitor.service - Virtual filesystem service - GNOME Online Accounts monitor...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor.service - Virtual filesystem service - digital camera monitor...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping gvfs-metadata.service - Virtual filesystem metadata service...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping gvfs-mtp-volume-monitor.service - Virtual filesystem service - Media Transfer Protocol monitor...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping gvfs-goa-volume-monitor.service - Virtual filesystem service - GNOME Online Accounts monitor...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor.service - Virtual filesystem service - digital camera monitor...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping gvfs-metadata.service - Virtual filesystem metadata service...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping gvfs-mtp-volume-monitor.service - Virtual filesystem service - Media Transfer Protocol monitor...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor.service - Virtual filesystem service - disk device monitor...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping pipewire-pulse.service - PipeWire PulseAudio...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service - Service for snap application snapd-desktop-integration.snapd->
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping tracker-miner-fs-3.service - Tracker file system data miner...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping xdg-desktop-portal-gnome.service - Portal service (GNOME implementation)...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.service - Portal service (GTK/GNOME implementation)...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping xdg-desktop-portal.service - Portal service...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping xdg-document-portal.service - flatpak document portal service...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping xdg-permission-store.service - sandboxed app permission store...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopped gnome-keyring-daemon.service - GNOME Keyring daemon.
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook wireplumber[1975]: disconnected from pipewire
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook gsd-a11y-settin[2391]: Error releasing name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.A11ySettings: The connection is closed
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook gsd-housekeepin[2397]: Error releasing name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Housekeeping: The connection is closed
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook gsd-screensaver[2421]: Error releasing name org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver: The connection is closed
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook kernel: rfkill: input handler enabled
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook gnome-remote-de[816]: Error releasing name org.gnome.RemoteDesktop: The connection is closed
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook gsd-sound[2437]: Error releasing name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sound: The connection is closed
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook gsd-color[2392]: Error releasing name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color: The connection is closed
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook gsd-sharing[2426]: Error releasing name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sharing: The connection is closed
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook gsd-rfkill[2418]: Error releasing name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Rfkill: The connection is closed
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook gsd-smartcard[2433]: Error releasing name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Smartcard: The connection is closed
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook gnome-shell[2233]: Could not release device '/dev/input/event4' (13,68): The connection is closed
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd-journald[357]: Journal stopped


While is it an old question, the answers in Ubuntu 16 reboots seconds after shutdown suggest the problem could be that the laptop get a spurious wake-up signal after shutting down, rather than say Ubuntu deciding to issue a reboot. Can you tell if the laptop shutdowns for a few seconds before re-starting, e.g. from looking at power LEDs?

I've just discovered one more observation. If I go to uefi and disable wifi - it resolves the problem. Now it is at least some hint, but I wonder what next. Should I investigate wake up on lan? Does it even apply to wifi as well? Or should I be looking for wifi related system errors?
Answering your question. No. The shutdown is very quick and it fully turns off the computer for 1-2 seconds. And then the keyboard backlight turns up again.

From the Super User Is Wake On LAN over WiFi possible? found a link to the Ubuntu Wake on WLAN documentation. You could try to disable WoWLAN in Ubuntu to see if that helps. I have no experience of using WoWLAN myself.

Have I seen this question before? The following link refers to the solutions to this rebooting-after-shutdown event for a HP Probook 450 G0 but is caused by very particular hardware present. unix.stackexchange.com/questions/675602/… You should also check the BIOS to see if there is any adjustable hardware that is capable of waking the PC such as ethernet or even that bluetooth device you have that seems to be having trouble shutting down. Good luck. –
